# Entity Framework Core: TPT

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, table-per-type, .net-5

.NET 5 preview 8 is just released and I've been testing the brand new TPT feature. I've installed the .NET 5 preview 8 Runtime and SDK.

I created a .NET Core class library, installed the `dotnet-ef` preview 8 NuGet, updated the `dotnet-ef` tool with the following command (administrator):

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef --version 5.0.0-preview.8.20407.4
```

I've build the following database model:

```
public class MintPlayerContext : DbContext
{
    // dotnet ef migrations add AddInitialEntities
    // dotnet ef --version

    public MintPlayerContext()
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Subject> Subjects { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Song> Songs { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=MintPlayerTPT;Trusted_Connection=True;ConnectRetryCount=0");
    }
}

[Table("Subjects")]
public class Subject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Memo { get; set; }
}

[Table("People")]
public class Person : Subject
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

[Table("Artists")]
public class Artist : Subject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int YearStarted { get; set; }
    public int YearQuit { get; set; }
}

[Table("Songs")]
public class Song : Subject
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime Released { get; set; }
}
```

and created/executed the database migrations:

```
dotnet ef migrations add AddInitialEntities
dotnet ef database update
```

Somehow this results in the following tables:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hI9ZS.png]

The glue between the tables seems to be missing. And even more odd is the TPT explanation at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-entity-framework-core-ef-core-5-0-preview-8/#table-per-type-tpt-mapping, where they state that the `Pet` table gets an `AnimalId` column. With TPT it's expected that the `Animal` table gets some `AnimalType` and `AnimalTypeId` columns.

So what's up with this? Is this a misconception or is Microsoft (due to performance considerations) still sticking to some spin-off database structure?

Comment: Look at the SQL definitions for the tables. The glue is in the identifying foreign keys, e.g. `CONSTRAINT [FK_Pets_Animals_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Id]) REFERENCES [Animals] ([Id])` No `AnimalId` column is mentioned in the linked article.

Comment: It seems silly because if you query for a Subject without knowing the exact type, EF Core will need to look up every table for all derived types...

Comment: Oh, I thought that a column actually needed to be present on the principle (Pets), but with sql server it appears not. But why is Microsoft not using 3NF for inheritance at database level?

Comment: `Pets.Id` *is* present. It doesn't have to be a *separate* column in a 1:0..1 relationship. That's an identifying foreign key (primary key of `Pets`, also foreign key to `Animals`) and it's common in 3NF. Why do you say it's not 3NF?

Comment: Probably a lack of theoretical background. I'm used to ORM's where the Subject table would contain a SubjectType and SubjectId column, but 3NF seems to be wider than this.

Comment: Don't you risk running into a state where a parent entity suddenly has multiple direct child entities with this implementation?